# Regex domain and path from url

Tags: regex, scala, url

I have a url:

```
https://widgets.shopifyapps.com/channel_admin/embeds/new?id=1243326021&product_handle=s-n-ph-m-4&product_name=S%25E1%25BA%25A3n%2520ph%25E1%25BA%25A9m%25204&first_variant_id=3897975749
```

I want to use a Regex to get the domain and path. 
I have tried following regex syntax: `(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?([A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+)/?.*"`
Which has following output: `widgets.shopifyapps.com`
But, I want to output: `widgets.shopifyapps.com/channel_admin/embeds/new`
I am using Scala. Please help me extract the domain above. Thank you!

Comment: `(?:https?://)?([^?]+)`

Comment: @revo : you should put that in an answer and explain it. This will make the question and answer handy for other people with similar questions.

Comment: I saw that it neither needs explanation nor is complicated so it would fit well in a comment. @RubenPirotte

Comment: @TuanMang, please share the regex-related code you are using.

Comment: You can use see :   https://regex101.com/r/yJ1rN2/1

Comment: @revo That sounds a bit arrogant for people like us who are struggling with regex expressions. Everything is easy when you already know it...

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve that. One is a non-regex one using Java [`URL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) class ([demo](https://ideone.com/Q6qELC)):

```
import java.net.URL;
object Main extends App {
    val a_url = new URL("https://widgets.shopifyapps.com/channel_admin/embeds/new?id=1243326021&product_handle=s-n-ph-m-4&product_name=S%25E1%25BA%25A3n%2520ph%25E1%25BA%25A9m%25204&first_variant_id=3897975749");
    print(s"${a_url.getHost()}${a_url.getPath()}");
}
```

Or, you can use a *matching* regex [`.*?://([^?]+).*`](https://regex101.com/r/lW2pJ9/2) and grab the Group 1 contents:

```
val a_url = "https://widgets.shopifyapps.com/channel_admin/embeds/new?id=1243326021&product_handle=s-n-ph-m-4&product_name=S%25E1%25BA%25A3n%2520ph%25E1%25BA%25A9m%25204&first_variant_id=3897975749";
val pattern = """.*?://([^?]+).*""".r
a_url match {
  case pattern(myval) => println(myval)
  case _ =>
}
```

See this [Scala demo](https://ideone.com/ennhIa)

Or a variation with a positive lookahead:

```
val a_url = "https://widgets.shopifyapps.com/channel_admin/embeds/new?id=1243326021&product_handle=s-n-ph-m-4&product_name=S%25E1%25BA%25A3n%2520ph%25E1%25BA%25A9m%25204&first_variant_id=3897975749";
val myval = """(?<=://)[^?]+""".r.findFirstIn(a_url).getOrElse("")
println(myval)
```

See [yet another demo](https://ideone.com/w4hW6q)